# Keeping track of total coins collected Swift 3

Tags: xcode, function, nsuserdefaults, swift3

I am trying to save the coins collected and add that amount to the total amount of coins collected by the user(in SpriteKit). With the current code, the coins currently do not save and nothing is added to the total. I am not sure why the coins are not saving as I do not see any notable mistakes in the code. Any help or explanations as to why this is not working the way it should would be greatly appreciated.

```
var totalCoins = 0

var coin = 0

let totalCoinDefault = UserDefaults.standard()

    totalCoins = totalCoinDefault.integer(forKey: "Totalcoin")

    totalCoinLabel.text = "\(totalCoins)"

        if ( coin > 0) {

            totalCoins += self.coin

            totalCoinLabel.text = String(format: "Totalcoin : %i", totalCoins)

            let totalcoinDefault = UserDefaults.standard()

            totalcoinDefault.setValue(totalCoins, forKey: "Totalcoin")

            totalcoinDefault.synchronize()

        }



func updateCoinTotal(){

   coinLabel.text = String(self.coin)

    totalCoinLabel.text = String(self.totalCoins)

    let totalCoinDefault = UserDefaults.standard()

    totalCoins = totalCoinDefault.integer(forKey: "")

    totalCoinLabel.text = "\(totalCoins)"

    if (self.coin > 0) {

        totalCoins += self.coin

        totalCoinLabel.text = NSString(format:  "%i", totalCoins) as String

        let totalcoinDefault = UserDefaults.standard()

        totalcoinDefault.setValue(totalCoins, forKey: "")

        totalcoinDefault.synchronize()

    }
```

Comment: Welp this is annoying. I've tried revamping your code a bit and every time I try to see if there's a value stored in the NSUserfefault and I find nothing. Check it via Playground: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/0468c16c03fdbdf6717256d0a902a13d

Comment: I am going to check that now! @KFDoom

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the updated code that you had which should work for your coins:

```
totalCoins = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().integerForKey("Total Coins")

totalCoinLabel.text = "\(totalCoins)"

if ( coin > 0) {

    totalCoins += coin

    totalCoinLabel.text = String(format: "Total Coins: \(totalCoins)")

    NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setInteger(totalCoins, forKey: "Total Coins")

}



func updateCoinTotal() {

    coinLabel.text = String(coin)

    totalCoinLabel.text = String(totalCoins)

    totalCoins = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().integerForKey("Total Coins")

    totalCoinLabel.text = "\(totalCoins)"

    if (coin > 0) {

        totalCoins += coin

        totalCoinLabel.text = NSString(format:  "%i", totalCoins) as String

        NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setInteger(totalCoins, forKey: "Total Coins")


}
```

But the coins Int will always equal zero so totalCoins will never be updated.

This is the code that I would use for collecting coins:

```
 func colledCoin() {
     totalCoins += 1
     coin += 1

     totalCoinLabel.text = String(totalCoins)
     coinLabel.text = String(coin)

     NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setInteger(totalCoins, forKey: "Total Coins")
 }

func updateCoinLabels() {
     totalCoins = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().integerForKey("Total Coins")
     totalCoinLabel.text = String(totalCoins)
 }
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Would I need to use the `totalCoinDefault.synchronize()` command?

Comment: You don't need to use it.